# List LinkedList ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

```
List arrayList = new ArrayList();
List linkedList = new LinkedList();

arrayList = linkedList;
```

`arrayList` is an instance of `ArrayList`. `linkedList` is a instance of `LinkedList`. So if assign `linkedList` to `arrayList`, it should hit error but why does not?

Comment: The reference types for both are List. It's perfectly fine to do so.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam Not sure where you are getting `Integer` from.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam No you won't.  Did you even try the exact code the OP posted?  I did.  No compile-time or run-time error.

Comment: I was doing `ArrayList arrayList`. That would be why there were exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`arrayList` is a *variable*.  It is declared to be a variable of type `List`, which means it can become a reference to any object of *any* type that implements `List`.  It doesn't matter that the first thing you assign to it is an `ArrayList`; you can reassign any other object reference to it later, as long as it implements `List`.

It helps to keep your terminology straight.  Your question seems to talk about assigning one *object* to another *object*, or one *list* to another *list*, but that's not what is happening.  You're assigning an object (actually a reference to an object) to a *variable*.  And when you assign something to a variable, the value that was previously in the variable has no effect on the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is a List type object, a LinkedList is also a List type object (inheritance). This is why assigning one to another works without a problem.

More specifically, List is an interface, implemented by AbstractList type objects which in turn are the base for ArrayLists.

You can see that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), after the black line.